# How to get FOR loop output into text file?

Tags: windows, for-loop, cmd

How to save the for loop output in text file?

My try is

```
for /F "tokens=5-6" %K in ('git fetch -v 2^>^&1 ^| findstr /B /C:"Receiving objects:"') do echo %K %L
```

Here I need to get line bold formatted line from the windows cmd.exe output.

> remote: Counting objects: 760, done.
>   remote: Compressing objects: 100% (366/366), done.
>   remote: Total 760 (delta 429), reused 688 (delta 386)R
>   **Receiving objects: 100% (760/760), 8.02 MiB | 436.00 KiB/s, done.**
>   Resolving deltas: 100% (429/429), done.

To be frank, I don`t know how this line working. I am newbie to cmd.exe

[OR]

How to get the fetching details in the text file?

```
git init & git remote add origin https://gitlab.company.com/project.git & (git fetch -v > test.txt)
```

Either I need to get it in text file or string in the C# coding.

Answer (score 0):

It is not really clear which data you want to write into which file. I assume you want from the line starting with `Receiving objects:` just `8.02 MiB` written into a file which I named in batch code below `info.txt`.

```
@echo off
del info.txt 2>nul
for /F "tokens=1,2,5,6" %%A in ('git fetch -v 2^>^&1') do (
    if "%%A %%B" == "Receiving objects:" echo %%C %%D>>Info.txt
)
```

The command **FOR** executes the command line `git fetch -v 2>&1`.

The error output to **STDERR** is redirected to **STDOUT** using `2>&1` whereby the operators `>` and `&` must be escaped here with caret character `^` to be interpreted as literal characters on parsing **FOR** command line by Windows command interpreter, but later on execution of `git fetch -v 2>&1` being interpreted as redirection operators.

I don't know if it is really necessary for your task to redirect error messages also to standard output handle for standard messages. I don't think so and therefore you can most likely replace `2^>^&1` by `2^>nul` to suppress error messages output by `git` by redirecting them device **NUL**.

The output of the executed command written to **STDOUT** is captured by **FOR** and processed line by line. Empty lines and lines starting with a semicolon are skipped. All other lines are processed with the specified options.

Each line is split up by **FOR** into substrings (tokens) using space and tab character as delimiter. The line of interest is therefore split up into:

1. `Receiving`
2. `objects:`
3. `100%`
4. `(760/760),`
5. `8.02`
6. `MiB`
7. `|`
8. `436.00`
9. `KiB/s,`
10. `done.`

With `tokens=1,2,5,6` it is specified that only first, second, fifth and sixth string are of interest and should be assigned to loop variables. The first one is assigned to loop variable `A` specified in **FOR** command line. The second one is assigned to loop variable being next in ASCII table which is `B`. That's the reason why loop variables are case-sensitive while environment variables aren't. The fifth string is assigned to loop variable `C` and the sixth string to loop variable `D`.

If **FOR** can determine at least one token (first string in this case), it executes the command(s).

The **IF** condition compares case-sensitive the first two tokens from line with a space between with `Receiving objects:` to determine if the current line is a line with data of interest.

If this string comparison is successful, the other two tokens are output to **STDOUT** redirected into a file with appending the data in case of the output contains multiple lines with `Receiving objects:`.

But if you want the entire line written into the text file, you can use:

```
@echo off
del info.txt 2>nul
for /F "tokens=1,2*" %%A in ('git fetch -v 2^>^&1') do (
    if "%%A %%B" == "Receiving objects:" echo %%A %%B %%C>>Info.txt
)
```

The asterisk after `2` means that after getting second space/tab delimited string the rest of the line should not be further split up and assigned to third loop variable `C` which means for this input example:

- `A` ... `Receiving`
- `B` ... `objects:`
- `C` ... `100% (760/760), 8.02 MiB | 436.00 KiB/s, done.`

But for just getting all lines starting with `Receiving objects:` written into file `info.txt` the following command line can be used within a command prompt window:

```
git fetch -v | findstr /B /C:"Receiving objects:" >info.txt
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `del /?`
- `echo /?`
- `findstr /?`
- `for /?`

Read also the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx).

Comment: I do not use the bat file i use it directly in command prompt.I used this command `del info.txt 2>nul for /F "tokens=1,2,5,6" %%A in ('git fetch -v 2^>^&1') do if "%A %B" == "Receiving objects:" echo %C %D>>Info.txt` in windows command prompt. But I got the output `C:\Users\path\Info.txt` in the text file

Comment: As help of command __FOR__ output with `for /?`explains, loop variables must be referenced with `%I` on command prompt and `%%I` within a batch file. You did that for `"%A %B"` and `%C %D`, but forgot to change `%%A` to `%A` on loop variable definition. I have added to the answer also a single command line for filtering output for lines starting with "Receiving objects:" written into a text file.

Comment: If I run the command `del info.txt 2>nul for /F "tokens=1,2,5,6" %A in ('git fetch -v 2^>^&1') do if "%A %B" == "Receiving objects:" echo %C %D>>Info.txt` in the **cmd.exe** I get the text `C:\Users\path\Info.txt` in the Info.txt file

Comment: If I run the `git fetch -v | findstr /B /C:"Receiving objects:" >info.txt` maens, I get the empty text file.

Comment: Please note that `del info.txt 2>nul` is one command line and `for /F "tokens=1,2,5,6" %A in ('git fetch -v 2^>^&1') do if "%A %B" == "Receiving objects:" echo %C %D>>Info.txt` is another command line. You can use both on one command line only by using an ampersand between. I don't have `git` installed and therefore can't try the commands. What happens if you run `git fetch -v >info.txt` and open next `info.txt`? Does it contain the lines or is it empty because `git` outputs the messages to handle __STDERR__ instead of __STDOUT__ as native Windows console applications do?

Comment: You have to use `git fetch -v  2>&1 | findstr /B /C:"Receiving objects:" >info.txt` if `git` outputs the messages to __STDERR__ instead of __STDOUT__. It would be also interesting which encoding (ANSI, UTF-8, UTF-16) is used by `git` on printing the messages to whatever handle.